# How to cast from a list with objects into another list.

Tags: c#, list, casting

I have an Interface [BindControls] which takes data from GUI and store it into a list „ieis”.

After that, Into another class, which sends this data through WebServices, I want to take this data from „ieis” and put it into required by WS Class fields (bottom is a snippet of code)

This is the interface:

```
void BindControls(ValidationFrameBindModel<A.B> model)
        {
            model.Bind(this.mtbxTax, (obj, value) =>
            {
                var taxa = TConvertor.Convert<double>((string)value, -1);

                if (taxa > 0)
                {
                    var ieis = new List<X>();

                    var iei = new X
                    {
                        service = new ServiceInfo
                        {
                            id = Constants.SERVICE_TAX
                        }, 
                        amount = tax,
                        currency = new CurrencyInfo
                        {
                            id = Constants.DEFAULT_CURRENCY_ID
                        }
                    };
                    ieis.Add(iei);
                }
            },"Tax");
        }
```

This is the intermediate property:

//**********************

```
class A 
{
  public B BasicInfo
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

 class B
        {

            public X Tax
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
        }
}
```

//***********************

This is the class which sends through WS:

```
void WebServiceExecute(SomeType someParam)
        {
//into ‚iai’ i store the data which comes from interface

            var iai = base.Params.FetchOrDefault<A>( INFO, null);

            var convertedObj = new IWEI();
            //...            
            var lx = new List<X>();

 //1st WAY: I tried to put all data from ‚Tax’into my local list ‚lx’
            //lx.Add(iai.BasicInfo.Tax); - this way is not working

    //2nd WAY: I tried to put data separately into ‚lx’ 
            var iei = new X
            {
                service = new ServiceInfo
                {
                    id = iai.BasicInfo.Tax.service.id
                },
                amount = iai.BasicInfo.Tax.amount,
                currency = new CurrencyInfo
                {
                   id = iai.BasicInfo.Tax.currency.id
                }
            };

            lx.Add(iei);

// but also is not working
```

Can you help me please to suggest how to implement a way that will fine do the work (take data from ‚ieis’ and put her into ‚lx’).
Thank you so much

Comment: When you say "not working" are you getting compiler errors, runtime errors?  What exactly is happening?

Comment: 1st WAY: didn't add any data to lx [see here: http://s2.ipicture.ru/uploads/20110921/Sl2ViVSX.png   ].                               2nd WAY: gives System.NullPointerException.

Comment: It sounds to me like iai.BasicInfo.Tax is null, this would explain the null reference exception in #2, and why you don't have any data in #1 (has one null reference).  Can you stop in a debugger and verify, or log/console whether == null?

Comment: @James Michael Hare, yes, iai.BasicInfo.Tax is null ... how do i implement to be possible to extract data from it ?

Comment: maybe there should be other way to store data into "Tax" or another property, object.

Comment: It's not clear why you've got a nested type B within class A...

Comment: @Jon Skeet, because I made bind through A, and Subbind through B. B is dependent of A. Thank you Jon, I resolved this problem.

Comment: Thank you James Michael Hare.   PLEASE CLOSE THIS TOPIC.

Comment: @meorfi: Do you want me to put the null part in an answer so you can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in my comment, it looks like iai.BasicInfo.Tax is null, once you find out why that is null your original `Add()` (#1) will work.

Comment: I found that Tax was null. After i made the mechanism to put values into it all works fine. Thank you